# How to disable the autocomplete menu but still get words completed?

Tags: autocompletion

When I use `<c-p>` to autocomplete, a list of possible completions appears, which can be annoying. Can this be disabled?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `set completeopt=longest` which will insert the longest common text of the matches. ([`:h 'completeopt'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27completeopt%27))

Be sure not to have `menu` nor `menuone` in `'completeopt'` to disable the autocompletion menu.

This way when you'll trigger autocomplete with `<C-n>` or `<C-p>` you will not have the menu open but the word will be complete with as many letters as possible.